# Assembly x86-64 2D array, extra address after each row

Tags: memory, assembly, multidimensional-array

I am using x86-64 assembly and compiling with a -m32 flag. The code sends in the first arg that is a double pointer to a multidimensional int array board[width][height], second arg is width, final arg is height. When I run it in gdb to check the memory addresses after each row where it should continue into the next row there is a "25" in the value and the next address continues the next row. So when it should be read as

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

the memory looks like

```
1 2 3 25
4 5 6 25
7 8 9
```

if 0x400 was the address of the first value, the values at the following addresses will look like

```
0x400=1
0x404=2
0x408=3
0x412=25
0x416=4
0x420=5
0x424=6
0x428=25
0x432=7
0x432=8
0x436=9
```

when I think it should look like

```
0x400=1
0x404=2
0x408=3
0x412=4
0x416=5
0x420=6
0x424=7
0x428=8
0x432=9
```

I tried to work around this but depending on the dimensions of the array, the number of "invisible columns" changes in a way I don't understand.

the args that get called are

```
void update(int **board, int width, int height)
```

and my assembly looks like

```
.file   "xxxxxx.c"
.text
.globl update
.type   update, @function
update:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

movl 8(%ebp),%ecx
movl 12(%ebp),%edx
movl 16(%ebp),%eax

movl (%ecx),%eax
movl (%eax),%edx

movl %edx,(%eax)
movl %eax,(%ecx)
movl %ecx,8(%ebp)

movl %ebp,%esp
ret
```

Why does this happen and how can I get the array to work normally in the memory addresses?

Comment: The elements of `int**` style 2D arrays are not guaranteed to be consecutive in memory. You should use the first level pointer array to access the sub-arrays.

Comment: Makes sense, I considered an int** syle 2D array to be the same as a int[][] array. I saw that in my textbook that 2D arrays have consecutive memory spots for each index and assumed it was the same for int**. Thank you!